# stream audio in Firefox

Tags: 16.04, sound, streaming

On a fresh installation of 16.04 Firefox will not stream audio from `msnbc.com/listen`

I tried this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install flashplugin-installer
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

I found a solution in the comments at this link.

[Link to a solution to this problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103311/how-to-make-firefox-stream-tv-and-radio)

I am looking for a better solution that can be implemented more quickly. I tried the solution (which involves re-installing Ubuntu) but it did not solve the problem.

The following was also tried.

```
sudo apt remove flashplugin-installer
sudo apt purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt remove adobe-flashplugin
sudo apt purge adobe-flashplugin
sudo apt remove firefox
sudo apt purge firefox
sudo apt install firefox
```

Notes: The Opera browser has no problem with that audio source. Youtube audio also works. Note that Adobe Flash or Shockwave Flash are actually not even necessary in Firefox. I have another 16.04 computer with the Shockwave Flash (plugin for Firefox) disabled and yet audio will stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to install support for "restricted" media formats.

Information is at this link:

[Ubuntu Restricted Formats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats)

Quoting from that webpage:

> Ubuntu strives to make all of the most important software available to
>   its users automatically. However patent and copyright restrictions
>   (see Ubuntu License Policy) complicate distribution of software to
>   support non-free formats.
>
> However, you can install the ability to play popular non-free media
>   formats, including DVD, MP3, Quicktime, and Windows Media formats, by
>   following the instructions below.
>
> Ubuntu’s commitment to only include completely free software by
>   default means that proprietary media formats are not configured “out
>   of the box”. See Ubuntu’s Free Software Philosophy and the Free
>   Formats page for a more comprehensive discussion of these issues.

The command is:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```