# install Firefox from the "Ubuntu Software" application

Tags: 16.04, firefox

After using **Ubuntu Software** to remove Firefox Web Browser I have the option to again remove Firefox Web Browser. How do I get the installation control instead of the remove control?

Before removing the browser:

[image: before]
After removing the browser the dialog is the same: it shows a remove control. After closing the **Ubuntu Software** application and restarting it, it will still show a remove control.

I have a need to reinstall Firefox without using the command line because the command line is not yielding satisfactory results.

Note that I am not interested in "Firefox Quantum". Note there is a bug wherein the label next to the Firefox icon is "Firefox" when in fact it might be better as "Firefox Quantum" but that can be posted as yet another askubuntu.com problem.

Comment: Could you please expand on "... *need to reinstall Firefox without using the command line because the command line is not yielding satisfactory results*"? The root of the problem seems to be related to this sentence. What's exactly is the problem?

Comment: Also I think you have a slight misconception, you *cannot* (easily) avoid Firefox **Quantum**. All the currently supported Firefox versions (v57+) are Quantum. There is no bug, *both* of the entries in your screenshot are indeed Firefox Quantum, the [first one is a snap package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/972411/why-are-there-2-packages-for-some-applications-e-g-chromium-in-ubuntu-softwar).

Comment: @pomsky The command line remove and purge of Firefox is not fixing this problem:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112664/stream-audio-in-firefox-from-msnbc-com-listen

Comment: I'm avoiding Quantum too - I use Firefox 52.9 ESR. It is **unsecure**, but you can install it following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/977140/66509). About two firefoxes in the software - one may be a Snap (check with `snap list | grep firefox`).

Comment: @h2o I'm confused, why do you think removing and reinstalling Firefox *specifically using the GUI application* would solve the problem?

Comment: @pomsky I don't presume that `sudo apt remove firefox` uninstalls Firefox because it might be `sudo apt remove FireFox9` or it might be something else. Since I don't presume that I am doing right on the command line I don't want to use the command line.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that other package operations are "in progress" or that your package system is in a broken state (possibly from commands you ran previously) which means hitting "Remove" in the Ubuntu Software application is simply queuing these actions and not actually executing them.

Also of note is that one of those Firefox packages I believe is a Snap package.

> I have a need to reinstall Firefox without using the command line because the command line is not yielding satisfactory results.

It's worth noting that Ubuntu Software, other package managers, and most every Linux program actually are interfaces that eventually run commands on the command line. This means that if something doens't work on the command line it's not very likely to work in a GUI, except when the GUI developers have added a bit of helper code to avoid common mistakes.

You can check if Firefox is installed using:

```
dpkg -l firefox
```

If it's installed, you'll see this:

```
ii  firefox                  64.0+build3-0ubun amd64             Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
```

That `ii` in the first column means it's installed.

It's worth mentioning that Firefox and many other applications can be added or removed, but they also store lots of files. For example, if I want I can copy my `~/.mozilla/firefox` directory from one installation to another and it will keep all my plugins, cookies, etc. intact. This is because applications in Linux cannot store files in system privileged areas of the disk and therefore keep their configuration files within your home directory (`~`)

Separate from the files in your home directory there are commands such as `apt purge` which will removes a package and it's associated *system configuration files* but to the best of my knowledge never removes any user configuration files.

## Cool, but how do I reinstall Firefox using the GUI?

I would suggest you first see if your package system is in a broken state by simply running:

```
sudo apt install firefox --reinstall
```

If this complains and says you have a broken package system then it explains why Ubuntu Software app isn't working. If it complains an existing `dpkg` process is already running, that also explains why the app isn't doing what you expect, and you should probably reboot Ubuntu.

Also as user [pomsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/480481/pomsky) mentions Firefox Quantum and Firefox are effectively the same thing now. There exists no officially supported version of Firefox that doesn't use the changes presented from Quantum, which essentially change how it uses multiple threads and other UI improvements. You can, in theory, grab a much older version of Firefox using:

```
apt install firefox=55.0
```

**You probably do not want to actually do that as you'll be running an insecure version of Firefox**

Comment: Nice, very detailed! Covers all the bases. The *first one* in OP's screenshot is a snap package.

Comment: `sudo apt install firefox --reinstall` was tried before I used the GUI installer. `sudo apt install firefox --reinstall` fails to fix the following problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112664/stream-audio-in-firefox-from-msnbc-com-listen